# Linux Permissions vsftpd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I have mybb installed and running in `/var/www/forums`.

I have two users part of the `www` group, `logan` and `www-data`.

I have the recursive permissions of forums directory set to:

```
chmod -R 755 forums
chown -R www-data:www forums
```

I have `vsftpd` set to `write-enable=YES`.

I can't upload a file! I get this on my filezilla:

```
    Status:  Starting upload of C:\Users\l162student\Desktop\money.png
    Command:    PASV
    Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (174,102,254,169,249,243).
    Command:    STOR money.png
    Response:   553 Could not create file.
    Error:  Critical file transfer error
```

If you need any log files or `conf` files just ask.

**UPDATE:** I just tried `775` and it lets me write files, BUT...
The files are all:

```
Owner Group  33 1005  -rwxrwxr-x
```

and the new files I upload are showing up as only:

```
Owner Group  1000 1005  -rw-r--r--
```

I want new files to INHERIT the folders permissions OR just show up as:

```
Owner Group  33 1005  -rwxrwxr-x
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What your distribution?

Comment: root@Citation:/var/www# cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.04.2 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.2 LTS)"
VERSION_ID="12.04"
root@Citation:/var/www#

Comment: Basically to get it to "work" how I want it too I have to ssh in after each upload and `chmod -R 775 forums` so annoying and I just want it to work correctly...

Comment: Sure, send away just don't want something complicated, also since I have posted this, I have gotten it to work. The Solution is the vsftpd config umask.... I don't know how I missed this.

Answer (score 0):

Using umask in the FTP config sets the Permissions on uploaded files, really what needed to be done was just setting users and groups properly. Admin/mod you may delete this question.

Comment: If you want a question deleted you can flag it for a moderators attention, or with enough rep cast a close vote on it.  However, the purpose of SE sites is to have questions and answers for them, so even though you solved your problem the larger purpose is so that others with the same problem may find your answer and benefit from it.  With that said, welcome to Unix&Linux Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your VSFTPD switching to passive mode.

Follow these instructions.

1 . open file

```
vim /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

And write

```
pasv_min_port=49152
pasv_max_port=65534
```

Save and close

2 . open file

```
     vim  /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config
```

And write

```
IPTABLES_MODULES="ip_conntrack_ftp"
```

Save and close.

3. Restart vsftpd service

   ```
          service vsftpd restart
   ```

Answer (score -2):

In this file: `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`:

```
#umask=002
```

Problem solved!

Comment: Please expand this answer. Though it might be the solution, it's doesn't really explain how in much detail.